# In typescript, type can't be referenced after computation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was expecting ts can figure out the type did not change after computation.

```
type Degree = 0 | 90 | 180 | 270;

const a: Degree = 90;

const b: Degree = 180;

// Error
const c: Degree = a + b;

// Error
const d: Degree = (a + b) % 360;
```

Comment: I think the RHS has to be either one of your four integer literals, or a function call that returns type `Degree`. Unfortunately, a `+` expression is neither. You could define your own `add` for this type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the result as `Degree`. Have a look at [Numeric Literal Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types)

```js
type Degree = 0 | 90 | 180 | 270;

const a: Degree = 90;

const b: Degree = 180;


const c = (a + b) as Degree;
const d = (a + b) % 360 as Degree;;
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDmAnC0C8UAMUA+UCcWuAjAByFQBMA7BgNwBQ9AxgPYB2AzsFAIYBcsBMjT46jVp24AjAXCQoo6UmPHsuUJoqgAKHlADUUKQEpeHQfIgMJ6gCZbdBo6YCkUAMwA2LD3NzhtLRAA)